# MVC LINQ where UserID is equal to the authenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am listing some data from my SQL Server database in a table with MVC. What i need is to be able to display only the data where the UserID is equal to the actual authenticated User.

This is what i have done at this time:

```
 public class ManageViewModel
  {
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public string Format { get; set; }
  }
```

My View:

```html
@model IEnumerable<Transcode.Models.ManageViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Actual Format</th>
        <th>Requested Format</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.FileName</td>
            <td>@item.ContentType</td>
            <td>@item.Format</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My Controller and LINQ query:

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Model = from file in db.Conversions
                    join codec in db.Codecs on file.CodecID equals codec.CodecID
                    where file.UserID.Equals(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    select new ManageViewModel
                    {                            
                        FileName = file.FileName,
                        ContentType = file.ContentType,
                        Format = codec.Format
                    };
        return View(Model);

    }
}
```

I get the following error in my @foreach (var item in Model):

*An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: 
Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are comparing apples (integers) to oranges (boolean):

```
where file.UserID.Equals(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Shouldn't you be comparing apples (integers) to apples (integers) instead? So you could start by getting the id of the currently authenticated user using the [`GetUserId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getuserid(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId%28System.Security.Principal.IIdentity%29) extension method:

```
string userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

then convert it to an integer or whatever the underlying types of your identifiers is:

```
int id = int.Parse(userId);
```

and then you can compare in your LINQ clause:

```
where file.UserID == id
```

And last but not least, since you are dealing with users, your `Index` action should be decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute to ensure that only authenticated users can call it:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! Actually my UserID is a string and not a int so i don't need to parse the userID.

Comment: Cool, then it's even easier.